# I dont know how to write outside of main in C, could you tell me what I did wrong?

Tags: c, encryption, compiler-errors

Hello I'm trying to make the function below outside of my main code in C but it isnt compiling and I dont get what I did wrong could you please give a pointer the right way (pun intended)

```
int moveAlp (char string [])
{

    char var0[1000];
    char lt0;
    int x=0;
    while (string[x])
    {
        lt0=string[x];
        if (lt0 == 'z')
        {
            var0[x]=(char)lt0-25;
        }
        else
        {
            var0[x]=(char)lt0+1;
        }
        x++;
    }
    printf("%s", var0);
}
```

EDIT:Forgot to put up my error

> interwebcharlie.c: In function ‘main’:
>       interwebcharlie.c:64:6: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[1000]’ from type ‘int’
>     var1=moveAlp(string);

Comment: if it's not compiling, you MUST be getting a compiler error explaining WHY it's not compiling... don't make us guess... TELL US what that error(s) is.

Comment: "It's not compiling" - well obviously it's giving you some kind of error message. Don't you think that is important to tell us?

Comment: The only error is that your function says it returns an `int` but there is no `return` statement in the code.  Either change the return type to `void` or decide what different values you are going to return.  If you only ever return a single value (such as 0), there's very little point in having the function return the value.

Comment: Also I would decide whether you want the function to return a value or whether you want it to print. Functions that print and do other things other than computations are called "side effects" and its generally nicer for the logic when you make specific functions which do side effects and the rest which do no side effects

Comment: Yes I'm just printing to check if it works but I really just want 25 different variabels made using this function

Comment: The error message is about where you are calling `moveAlp()`, not the function definition itself. Presumably, you have `char var1[1000];` and therefore `var1 = moveAlp(string);` is wrong because `moveAlp()` returns an `int` and in any case you cannot assign directly to an array.  Also, you should not return a local variable from `moveAlp()`, so don't try `return var0;` in the function.

Comment: what is var1 and what is string in line 64 in interwebcharlie.c ?

Comment: Just realised I'm trying to return an array from a function so that won work anyways..
int var1=moveAlp(string, 1);
char string [5000];

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined as `int moveAlp(char string[])` but doesn't actually return anything, and certainly no `int`. Also, `string` might be a reserved identifier (or maybe I'm making stuff up, could be it's just in C++..). Are you trying to write a cesar-cipher? It seems like you're going to try to use `var0` in the rest of your program, which would be very bad, because that's a local variable and will be out of scope by the time you want to use it outside of `moveAlp()`. The error-message you got seems to refer to something outside of `moveAlp()` (specifically, in `main()`, as the error explicitly says...), so it'd be nice to see the rest of your code.